# Allocating memory for struct "error"

Tags: c, struct

I´m just playing around with C when I got a problem I can´t figure out.

I have a struct, lets say

```
typedef struct Node
{
    void * data;
    int id;
}Node;
```

And my program looks like

```
void Node_Init(Node *node)
{
   node = malloc(sizeof(Node));
   node->id = 5;
}

int main()
{
   Node *node;
   Node_Init(node);
   printf("ID %d", node->id);
}
```

When I run this code and node->id gets printed I get a random number? It´s like node->id gets allocated on the stack and not the heap?

Because when I do Node *node; If I do `Node *node = malloc(sizeof(Node));` It works, but If I remember correctly its not needed to do like that. Anyone can help me out saying why this happens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> void Node_Init(Node *node) 
> {    
>       node = malloc(sizeof(Node));   
>       node->id = 5; 
> }
>
> int main() 
> {    
>      Node *originalnode;    
>      Node_Init(originalnode);    
>      printf("ID %d", node->id); 
> }
> ```

Why your solution does not work?
When you call the function the parameter node becomes local in the `Node_Init` scope. Then you assign the node (which is local) the value returned by malloc. After the function return value of this `node` becomes unavailable. No change in the `originalnode`' It is same uninitialised as it was before. your function is an equivalent of:

```
void Node_Init(Node *node) 
{
      Node *x;    
      x = malloc(sizeof(Node));   
      x ->id = 5; 
}
```

---

To change the `originalnode` you need to:

1. Pass the pointer to the originalnode. When you dereference this pointer to originalnode, and assign the value to the dereferenced object you change the `originalnode`
   2.
   Return the `node` and assign it to the `originalnode`

   ```
   void Node_Init(Node **node)
   {
      *node = malloc(sizeof(Node));
      (*node)->id = 5;
   }

   int main()
   {
      Node *node;
      Node_Init(&node);
      printf("ID %d", node->id);
   }
   ```

or

```
void *Node_Init(void)  // or Node *Node_Init(void)
{
   Node *node
   node = malloc(sizeof(Node));
   node->id = 5;
   return node;
}

int main()
{
   Node *node;
   node = Node_Init();
   printf("ID %d", node->id);
}
```

Dont forget to free it after the use

Comment: `*node->id = 5;` --> `(*node)->id = 5;` and `printf("ID %d", *node->id);` --> `printf("ID %d", node->id);`

Comment: noticed it mysellf thanks anyway

Comment: Also you should probably `free` memory and check if system gave you the memory.

Comment: You should explain what you changed and why

Comment: Well thanks for the answer but this just shows a solution (second one), that I already know about. I want to know why this happens, is it because if I do a pointer like int *a; it means that a is null = No adress?

Comment: @Labba added explanation